# Change controls properties outside Tabcontrol based on selected Tab

Tags: wpf, xaml, triggers, styles, tabcontrol

I am working with tabcontrol in WPF.
I want a button outside the tabcontrol to change to a dropdownbutton (combobox) based on certain choices(tab page selected)
Appreciate your help.

Comment: your question is very unclear

Comment: If tabpage selected is one then button should be a single button with a click, and if tabpage selected is 2 then button should transform into dropdownbutton giving users option of selecting multiple command on click.

Comment: Add both controls and toggle their visibility based on a datatrigger and the selectedindex of the tabcontrol

Comment: Can you give some sample code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add both controls to your layout and toggle their visibility based on a datatrigger and the selectedindex of the tabcontrol

```
    <ComboBox>
        <ComboBox.Style>
            <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=yourTabControl, Path=SelectedIndex}" Value="0">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ComboBox.Style>
    </ComboBox>
    <Button>
        <Button.Style>
            <Style TargetType="Button">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=yourTabControl, Path=SelectedIndex}" Value="1">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Button.Style>
    </Button>
```

Comment: Thanks. Let me give it a go !

Comment: if that helped you please mark it as answer for others to find